# Angular 4 @Input() value is undefined in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular

**month-detail.component.html**

```
import ...
@Component({
  template: `{{month?.id}} <app-month-date [month]="month"></app-month-date>`
})
export class MonthDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  month: Month;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.monthService.getMonth(+params["id"]))
      .subscribe(month => (this.month = month));
  }
}
```

**month-date.component.html**

```
<p>month-date works! {{month?.id}}</p>
```

**month-date.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Month } from "app/attendance/month";

@Component({
  selector: "app-month-date",
  ...
})
export class MonthDateComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() month: Month;
  ngOnInit() {
    //undefined --- here
    console.log(this.month);
  }}
```

month?.id shows correctly in `month-detail.component.html`, but month is undefined with tag `app-month-date` in `month-date.component.ts`.
Maybe not get the value on ngOnInit?

Comment: Yup it's undefined cause the ngOnInit will tigger before the month is set. In this case you want tot use **ngOnChanges**

Comment: If you *really* think about why you have `month?.id` instead of `month.id`, the answer will become apparent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can resolve this by ensuring the child component is not initialised before the month input value is sent to it by including an *ngIf in your parent template:

```
@Component({
  template: `{{month?.id}} <app-month-date *ngIf="month" [month]="month"></app-month-date>`
})
```